# hover out function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery("#markets_served").hover(function(){
    jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height", jQuery(this).height());
    if(jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height") == 35) {
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({height:'195px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
        jQuery("#btn_ms_close").css("display","inline");
    }
});

jQuery("#btn_ms_close").hover(function(){
    jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height", jQuery("#markets_served").height());
    jQuery("#markets_served").stop().animate({height:'35px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    jQuery(this).css("display","none");
});
```

Problem with hovering out. It wont work. It wont hover out when the mouse is out of the content that appears on hover.

http://uscc.dreamscapesdesigners.net/ - example at the bottom " Markets Covered"

Comment: you seem to have two on-mouse-over events here. you can pass two functions to hover(), one for on-moue-over, one for on-mouse-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simplier without data:

```
jQuery("#markets_served").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({height:'195px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    jQuery("#btn_ms_close").css("display","inline");
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({height:'35px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    jQuery("#btn_ms_close").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: BTW, you can store data "inside" any element, not only in document.body: e.g. `jQuery("#id").data("key", "value")`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) declaration on the jQuery site. You can specify a handler for the mouseover and mouseout event in one swoop. No need to calculate heights or bind another handler to a new div that appears.

```
$("#markets_served").hover(
  function () {
    //do this when over
  },
  function () {
    //do this when out
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use is like:

```
$('#el').hover(function(e) { /* hover; */ }, function(e) { /* unhover */ });
```

here is [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry I might be asking stupid questions. I am fairly new to jquery

Comment: in the first function you do all that should be done when mouse goes in, and in the second you're doing everything that should be done to get the element in the state before it was affected by the first function.

Answer (score 0):

When mouse comes in you increase the height of the div but you dont reset it when mouse is outside the div hence the issue.

You should do something like this:

```
jQuery("#markets_served").hover(
    function(){
        jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height", jQuery(this).height());
        if(jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height") == 35) {
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({height:'195px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
            jQuery("#btn_ms_close").css("display","inline");
        } , 
    function(){
            jQuery.data(document.body, "ms_height", jQuery("#markets_served").height());
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({height:'35px'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
            jQuery("#btn_ms_close").css("display","none");
        }


    });
```